# Common JNDI resources in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, jndi

I’m running a couple of servlet applications in Tomcat (5.5). All of the servlets use a common factory resource that is shared out using JNDI. At the moment, I can get everything working by including the factory resource as a GlobalNamingResource in the /conf/server.xml file, and then having each servlet’s META-INF/context.xml file include a ResourceLink to the resource. Snippets from the XML files are included below. NOTE: I’m not that familiar with tomcat, so I’m not saying that this is a good configuration!!!

However, I now want to be able install these servlets into multiple tomcat instances automatically using an RPM. The RPM will firstly copy the WARs to the webapps directory, and the jars for the factory into the common/lib directory (which is fine). But it will also need to make sure that the factory resource is included as a resource for all of the servlets.

What is the best way add the resource globally? I’m not too keen on writing a script that goes into the server.xml file and adds in the resource that way. 
Is there any way for me to add in multiple server.xml files so that I can write a new server-app.xml file and it will concatenate my settings to server.xml? Or, better still to add this JNDI resource to all the servlets without using server.xml at all?

p.s. Restarting the server will not be an issue, so I don’t mind if the changes don’t get picked up automatically.

Thanks

Snippet from server.xml

```
  <!-- Global JNDI resources -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>

  <Resource name="bean/MyFactory"
                auth="Container"
                type="com.somewhere.Connection"
                factory="com.somewhere.MyFactory"/> 
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

The entire servlet’s META-INF/context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <ResourceLink global="bean/MyFactory"
                name="bean/MyFactory"
                type="com.somewhere.MyFactory"/>
  </Context>
```

Comment: What does the factory resource do? I have a similar situation i am trying to resolve but not sure how. For example, is it possible to only create one instance of the object? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453109/using-jndi-to-share-servlet-session-objects-and-data-in-tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Tomcat 4, the recommendation has been not to put any JNDI information in the *server.xml* file. Check [Tomcat 5.5's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html):

> For Tomcat 5, unlike Tomcat 4.x, it is
>   NOT recommended to place 
>   elements directly in the server.xml
>   file. This is because it makes
>   modifying the Context configuration
>   more invasive since the main
>   conf/server.xml file cannot be
>   reloaded without restarting Tomcat.

I know you claim not to care about this, but trust me, your deployment team does, and the maintenance team will thank you later. Even if this means you end up thanking yourself.

If you need a JNDI setting to be shared among all webapps on a server, you should put it into the file $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml. In all likelihood, there will be an existing context.xml already in that location, but you should be able to write a simple app to add your resource nodes via your favorite language and whatever DOM builder comes bundled with it. Or, if you want to stick with the command line, check out [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipclp.html), which gives a few XML-processing shell scripts to help you out.

Good luck!

Comment: You have to put things that are shared by all Apps in the `server.xml` there is no other way to do it, and that is what the OP is doing given that they mention `<ResourceLink/>`

Answer (score 1):

actually we have a case where we cannot put (for example) jdbc configuration in the war: the customer will never let us know username and password for the production server, so we had to define the datasource in global server configuration and put a link in the context.xml of the app, like the op did.
The global configuration can be put either in server.xml or in tomcat's context.xml (it seems that the second approach is the one preferend on windows platform).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but have you instead considered putting all your config inside your *context.xml* file, instead of in *server.xml*?  This makes your web-app more fully self-contained, which sounds important to your deployment requirements.

I'd go as far to say it might be worth considering any refactoring necessary to ensure your apps can be fully self-contained if this can't be done at present.

Having worked on projects where I deployed /common/lib JARs and common resources, and been bitten by them in confusing and subtle ways (I eventually found out these were invariably my own fault btw, not blaming Tomcat here), I now favour a completely protective approach to my webapps: keep 'em completely independent.

But of course I don't fully know your circumstances, just some suggestions.

Comment: You have to put things that are shared by all Apps in the `server.xml` there is no other way to do it, and that is what the OP is doing given that they mention `<ResourceLink/>`

Comment: True but if you read my answer again you'll see I'm suggesting the OP might reconsider that objectve given his/her deployment requirements. I've found have sharing components can cause problems which fully self-contained apps don't suffer.

Comment: Somethings MUST be shared amongst Apps this way, for example the only way to share an Embedded Derby database is to put it in `server.xml` and then refer to the `JNDI` through `<ResourceLink/>`. There is no other way to do it and no other re-consideration for these types of things that can only be one of per JVM type Resources.

Answer (score 0):

This what I would do, I am using Maven 3, I would put the `server.xml` in my `resources` directory or some other directory I can run a `filter` on and dynamically replace and generate an appropriate `server.xml` when I do a package. You could then use the maven-rpm-plugin and automate the rpm generation as well.